# How to extract audio files from .ts files when I have their URLs only on python?

Tags: python, url, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a code in python which extracts `.ts` urls from `.m3u8` urls and process them to extract their content. I got the `.ts` urls but I need the audio files(`.wav`) of them to further process them and get text data from them.

PS: Some `.ts` URLs might not work at sometimes as they expire or for any other reason. They work at some time and they don't at some other time.

`ffmpeg` takes the downloaded `.ts` files as input but not URLs. Should I download each `.ts` file and call `ffmpeg`?

A few sample `.m3u8` links from which I got `.ts` links.

```
http://espn.tmedia.me/cache/bet.m3u8
Animal Planet
http://80.80.160.168/live/1/live.m3u8
CBS
http://161.0.157.50/PLTV/88888888/224/3221227041/03.m3u8
Classic Arts Showcase
https://classicarts.global.ssl.fastly.net/live/cas/master_3000k.m3u8
CMT Music
http://espn.tmedia.me/cache/cmt.m3u8
```

I have a nested list of `.ts` file URL for each `.m3u8` link in order, like:
`[[1.ts, 2.ts, 3.ts][a.ts,b.ts,c.ts]`....[empty lists when `.m3u8` link doesn't work]....[]..]

I need to get audio file for every `.ts` url and analyze it to get text data and make a new list which replaces the `.ts` links with their respective text data.